# Ошибка 403 при попытке открыть изображения, загруженные с телефона

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, formdata

Есть 2 поля для загрузки изображений. При нажатии на сабмит они через **аякс** уходят во **views** **Джанго**. Дальше они там обрабатываются и создаётся соответствующая запись в базе данных.

Проблема в том, что мой код работает только для загрузки изображений с компьютера. А при загрузке с мобильного телефона (айфон) просто создаётся запись в базе данных. В этой записи присутствуют ссылки на эти фотографии, но когда я пытаюсь их открыть - получаю ошибку **403**. Когда пытаюсь вручную сменить эти фото с админ страницы - получаю ту же ошибку - **403**.

**models.py**

```
from djlime.utils import get_file_path

class RequestUser(models.Model):
    main_photo = models.ImageField(_('main_photo'), upload_to=get_file_path)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(_('profile_photo'), upload_to=get_file_path)

    @property
    def upload_dir(self):
        return 'accounts/request_user/images'
```

**forms.py**

```
class IdentificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RequestUser
        fields = ('main_photo', 'profile_photo', )
        widget= {
            'main_photo': forms.FileInput(
                attrs={
                    'style': 'display: none',
                }
            ),
            'profile_photo': forms.FileInput(
                attrs={
                    'style': 'display: none',
                }
            )
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IdentificationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['main_photo'].widget.attrs = {'class':'file_dnl'}
        self.fields['profile_photo'].widget.attrs = {'class':'file_dnl'}

    def clean_image(self):
        cd_image = self.cleaned_data['main_photo']
        return cd_image

    def clean_image2(self):
        cd_image = self.cleaned_data['profile_photo']
        return cd_image
```

**views.py**

```
def identification_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IdentificationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if request.is_ajax():
            main_photo = request.FILES.get('file1')
            profile_photo = request.FILES.get('file2')
            RequestUser.objects.create(
            user = request.user,
            main_photo = main_photo,
            profile_photo = profile_photo
            )
            return HttpResponse('image upload success')
    else:
        form = IdentificationForm()
    identifications  = RequestUser.objects.filter(user = request.user)

    return render(request, 'accounts/identification.html', {'form': form, 'identifications': identifications})
```

**identification.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="edit_form new_event" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='bBfv5mapMAVzI35UGp0H4LfbKR9avG4id6Me01bRZfAefjzKwcL3xj1lDiLBBR5L' />
    <div class="field inline">
        <div class="subhead">Main photo:</div>
        <input type="file" name="main_photo" required class="file_dnl" id="id_main_photo" />
        <label for="foto1" class="id_foto">
            <div class="addPhoto">
                <div class="button" id='foto1_button'></div>
            </div>
        </label>
        <div id='profile_photo' style='display:none; text-align:center'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field inline">
        <div class="subhead">Profile photo:</div>
        <input type="file" name="profile_photo" required class="file_dnl" id="id_profile_photo" />
        <label for="foto2" class="id_foto">
            <div class="addPhoto">
                <div class="button" id='foto2_button'></div>
            </div>
        </label>
        <div id='profile_photo' style='display:none; text-align:center'></div>
    </div>

    <div class="center">
      <button class="submit mgln" type='button'>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$("input[name='main_photo']").change(function(){
     var filename = $(this).val().replace(/.*\\/, "");
     console.log(filename)
     $("#main_photo").html(filename).css('display', 'block');
});
$("input[name='profile_photo']").change(function(){
     var filename = $(this).val().replace(/.*\\/, "");
     console.log(filename)
     $("#profile_photo").html(filename).css('display', 'block');
});
$('#foto1_button').on('click', function(){
  document.getElementById("id_main_photo").click();
});
$('#foto2_button').on('click', function(){
  document.getElementById("id_profile_photo").click();
});
  var token = 'bBfv5mapMAVzI35UGp0H4LfbKR9avG4id6Me01bRZfAefjzKwcL3xj1lDiLBBR5L';
  $('.mgln').on('click', function(){
      formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file1', $('input[name=main_photo]')[0].files[0])
      formData.append('file2', $('input[name=profile_photo]')[0].files[0])
      $.ajax({
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
        type: "POST",
        url: "/identification/",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(result) {
          alert('Ok.');
        },
        error: function(result) {
          alert('Not ok.');
        }
      })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Каким браузеров отправляете? Возможно, он не поддерживает formdata?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData - пункт поддержка браузерами - > мобильные. Гарантированно поддержка базовых возможностей есть лишь у Android-браузер, Firefox и Opera mobile. В Safari mobile поддержка под вопросом.

Comment: Всё оказалось гораздо проще. Для файлов, которые грузились с айфона, кстанавливались 600 права (так как размер фото был большой).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Дело было не совсем в телефоне.*

Согласно документации, на файлы, которые превышают 2,5 Мб, устанавливаются права 600. По стечению обстоятельств, получилось, что файлы, загружаемые с телефона, весили больше 2,5 Мб.
Удалось решить эту проблему с помощью указания прав в `settings` проекта.

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0644
```

Также задал максимальный размер, загружаемого файла (равен 10 Мб)

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 10485760
```

[Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#file-upload-permissions)

Приведу цитату одного знакомого:

> Маленькие файлы писались сначала в память, а потом в медиа папку с
>   общим доступом на чтение. Большие - в темп и потом в медиа с чтением
>   только для владельца. Поскольку загружается это под одним
>   пользователем, а отдаётся под другим - вот тебе и 403 для больших.